# How do I get an empty associative array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I hopy my title makes sense. Right now my php output to my HTML document is working perfectly. Except when my SQL database is empty then I get errors all over the place. Here is my code:

```
<?php

// configuration
require("../includes/config.php"); 

$rows = CS50::query("SELECT symbol, shares FROM portfolios WHERE user_id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);
$cash = CS50::query("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);

$positions = [];
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $stock = lookup($row["symbol"]);
    $total = ($stock["price"] * $row["shares"]);

    if ($stock !== false)
    {
        $positions[] = [
            "name" => $stock["name"],
            "price" => $stock["price"],
            "shares" => $row["shares"],
            "symbol" => $row["symbol"],
            "total" => $total,
            "cash" => $cash[0]["cash"]
        ];
    }
}

// render portfolio
render("portfolio.php", ["positions" => $positions, "title" => "Portfolio"]);
?>
```

So if `$rows` in this case is empty then the positions array will throw an error. So i want it to be empty if `$rows` is empty. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: You should check if results are set. If it's not set you should set the values within the array to empty string.

Comment: in your front end you should use `if(!empty($positions)) {...}`

Comment: i agree with above mentioned comments, you can utilize count($yourArray) as well.. check if count is greater than zero..

Comment: you need to provide more info. What is this method doing `CS50::query` ? Is it PDO, mysql, mysqli. etc...?

Comment: @CodeGodie. There are functions given to me, not native to php or mySQL (but that i guess you already knew). That function simply lets me use mySQL commands in my PHP code. Sorry I cant really explain furthur, this is part of pset7 of and introduction to computer science course im taking.

Comment: in that case, I would first use `print_r` or `var_dump` to see what type of result the method gives me (could be a boolean or just an empty array, perhaps something else). Depending on that, then you can either directly use an array, or use an `if(!emtpy())` statement

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please vote it up; if it solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays don't throw errors, I assume you mean you're getting the error when you try to use the empty array. In that case, as mentioned in comments, just check that it's not empty using [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

```
    // render portfolio
    if (count($positions) === 0) {
        $positions[] = [
            "name" => "",
            "price" => 0,
            "shares" => 0,
            "symbol" => "",
            "total" => 0,
            "cash" => 0
        ];
    }
    render("portfolio.php", ["positions" => $positions, "title" => "Portfolio"]);
```